# Find out which process/app launched another process/app

Tags: process, kill

I have a process that when I kill it (using process explorer), it just comes back after about 30 seconds.

Is there any way to find out which process is restarting the process I am killing (so I can kill that one too)?

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution for this?

Comment: @Charlie - Alas, this question was asked and answered well over a decade ago, and I am not sure. I would recommend playing around with Process Explorer (by SysInternals) to find a solution. I marked that answer as the solution, so I probably found something there and forgot to come back and put in the details. (You may be better off re-asking the question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Process Explorer right click on that process, then Properties, the Image, and the Parent field shows that

Comment: That just says Services.exe.  The app that keeps getting restarted is not a Microsoft app (and Services.exe is).  I don't really know what Services.exe does, but I am leery of just killing it.

Comment: No, don't kill that one. It seems that program is set as a service, check the active services in your Windows system. I think Process Explorer also says which service a process belongs to.