# How to identify which process is launching Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, windows-11, virus-removal

I am using windows 11 and Outlook keeps opening randomly. I have closed it multiple times but its keeps opening again. I am suspecting my computer is infected and I want to identify which process is launching Outlook.

I have already tried Process Explorer mentioned by [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/365253/find-out-which-process-app-launched-another-process-app) , but it just shows Explorer.exe as the parent process.

So how do I identify which process  is launching Outlook?

Answer (score 0):

To turn off Outlook autostart, you can try the following methods:

1. Windows Key+R > shell:startup .
   See if you have Outlook here. If yes, delete it.
2. CTRL+SHIFT+ESC to invoke Task Manager > Under startup tab, see if Outlook is there. If yes, disable that.

Comment: Outlook is not in the Startup programs so thats not the cause

Comment: Notice that you updated the issue. Another program is using Outlook for a number of reasons. Normally all the add-ins listed in the Outlook Trust Center to see the possible culprits.

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back.